# Is the Schwa in English rounded or unrounded?

Tags: english, phonology

Wikipedia says that in principle the Schwa sound can be both rounded and unrounded. Can it be both in English, or does English always does one or the other?

Comment: It will just take the shape of whichever consonants surround it.

Comment: Up to a point, @curiousdannii.  But it seems to me that French-speakers tend to at least partly round their schwas more than English-speakers  -  it's one way we British 'put on a French accent'.

Comment: English shwa has no other central vowels to contrast with, so its height, rounding, and other features are variable. Certainly it will assimilate to rounded sounds.

Comment: @DavidGarner The French schwa is phonetically [ø] ~ [œ].